# Rename Folder/File located in a server using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a Macro which main function is to rename folders in a specific server location (Main folder). All the files on this Main Folder have the 3 first characters as numbers which are in sequential order. Since I'm changing them often I wanted a Macro which was able to rename the folders from a item up (this item would be the first 3 characters of a folders name)

The the issue I have is that since the files are in a server I cannot really change the name, it seams like I just can change the name which appears to the user but not the "real"/first name.

Perhaps with a couple of images it might help:
[image]

The code we are using is the following:

```
Private Sub PrintFolders()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFSO_2 As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objSubFolder As Object
    Dim fileExcel As Object
    Dim xpto As Object
    Dim objSubSubFile_Excel As Object
    Dim auxStringName As String, auxStringPath As String
    Dim i As Integer

    Application.StatusBar = ""

    'Get Folder Path
    auxStringPath = Range("C2").Text
    If auxStringPath = "" Then
        Err = 19
        GoTo handleCancel
    End If
    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(auxStringPath)
    i = 0
    'Get intBegin
    intBegin = CInt(Range("C3").Value)

    'loops through each folder in the directory and prints their names and path
    On Error GoTo handleCancel
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlErrorHandler
    'MsgBox "This may take a long time: press ESC to cancel"

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        Application.StatusBar = objSubFolder.Path & " " & objSubFolder.Name

        If CInt(Left(objSubFolder.Name, 3)) >= intBegin Then

            If intBegin < 10 Then
                auxStringName = "00" & CStr(intBegin + i) & Mid(objSubFolder.Name, 4)
            ElseIf intBegin < 100 Then
                auxStringName = "0" & CStr(intBegin + i) & Mid(objSubFolder.Name, 4)
            Else
                auxStringName = CStr(intBegin + i) & Mid(objSubFolder.Name, 4)
            End If

            For Each fileExcel In objSubFolder.Files
                If Right(fileExcel.Name, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(fileExcel.Name, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                    Name auxStringPath & "\" & objSubFolder.Name & "\" & fileExcel.Name As auxStringPath & "\" & objSubFolder.Name & "\" & Left(auxStringName, 3) & Mid(fileExcel.Name, 4)
                End If
            Next fileExcel

            Name auxStringPath & "\" & objSubFolder.Name As auxStringPath & "\" & auxStringName

            i = i + 1

        End If

    Next objSubFolder

handleCancel:

    If Err = 18 Then
        MsgBox "You cancelled"
    ElseIf Err = 19 Then
        MsgBox "Missing Path"
    End If

    Set objFSO = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing

End Sub
```

Does anyone can help on this? 
Does anzone has alreadz had a similar issue?

Comment: Does this have to be done using VBA? What about using the command line? If you have ssh access you might consider using SED commands, etc... as in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvjIcs-WLew

Comment: In VBA would be the "only" way for me once I don't have permitions to program in any other language. I was thinking about a .dll piece of code I could use integrated in the VBA Macro.